# Basic Python web scraping with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm pretty new to coding and recently I've started looking into web scraping. I've been following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ng2o98k983k) and also reading the BS4 documentation but I just can't see why my code isn't working.

I'm trying to extract [this post's headline](http://coreyms.com/development/best-sublime-text-features-and-shortcuts) with the webscraper but it looks like it can't find any tags that match "('div', class_='header')"

My code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

SOURCE = requests.get('http://coreyms.com/').text
SOUP = BeautifulSoup('SOURCE', 'lxml')

HEADER = SOUP.find('div', class_='header')
HEADLINE = HEADER.h2.a.href

print(HEADLINE)
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "WSCoreySchafer.py", line 10, in <module>
    HEADLINE = ARTICLE.h2.a.href
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'h2'
```

Comment: I'm confused which tag you're attempting to target using `HEADER = SOUP.find('div', class_='header')`, I'm not seeing a tag like that on the linked website. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: If you are trying to scrape `http://coreyms.com/development/best-sublime-text-features-and-shortcuts`, then you need to use that URL

Comment: 98/100 questions on SO like this are caused by website content that is dynamically added after page load.  BS4 does not execute any client-side JS (to load additional content).  Are you sure the data you're trying to target is actually in the raw HTML returned by your request (ie, your `SOURCE` var)?

Comment: @Cole There was a mistake in there but it doesn't seem to be what causes the error. I'll look further into it.

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm sotty, I don't think I phrased that too well. I'm trying to extract that post's headline off the website's homepage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line:

```
SOUP = BeautifulSoup('SOURCE', 'lxml')
```

tries to create a soup object from the string `'SOURCE'` not from the value stored in the variable `SOURCE`.

You're also looking for the wrong element in the html, you don't want a `<div>` with `class="header"`, you're actually looking for a `<header>` element (of which there are multiple on this page). I'd actually suggest looking for the `<h2>` element with `class="entry-title"`, which you can do like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

SOURCE = requests.get('http://coreyms.com/').text
SOUP = BeautifulSoup(SOURCE, 'lxml')

HEADER = SOUP.find('h2', class_='entry-title')
headline_href = HEADER.a['href']
print(headline_href)
```

which prints

```
http://coreyms.com/development/best-sublime-text-features-and-shortcuts
```

Comment: Now it just gives me a 'None'. I guess it manages to find all the tags except for the href itself, tho I might be wrong on that. But that's something already, thanks.

Comment: @PedroS if I run this code on my machine I get `http://coreyms.com/development/best-sublime-text-features-and-shortcuts`

Comment: Ok, running the new code prints out the exact URL, I think this may be it. Thank you so much for the help!